Need help Inheriting TUNGraph object defined by Snap.py
I'm trying to use some public code I found off GitHub for a research project and I first had to convert the code from Python2 to Python3 using 2to3. I am getting an error when I run this even though I am importing Snap correctly.
(https://i.sstatic.net/6x6RcLBM.png)
I am using Google Colab so the code I use to import snap is here:
Step 1: Clone the SNAP repository
!git clone https://github.com/snap-stanford/snap.git
Step 2: Install dependencies
!pip install numpy scipy
Step 3: Change directory and install SNAP
%cd snap
!make
!python setup.py install
Step 4: Import SNAP
from snap import *
Test import
print("SNAP imported successfully!")
Then the code I run is a long function but it starts here:
TGraphVX inherits from the TUNGraph object defined by Snap.py
class TGraphVX(TUNGraph):
And this is where I get the error
